# Picker view not updating

Tags: ios, json, swift

Due to some issues, I am trying to use Alamofire, here I have an Alamofire that gets an online JSON file, gets the four results, places them on the picker view, and refreshes so that they can show up. The code here works perfectly:

```
 Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://example.com/json.json", parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
            .responseJSON { response in
                print(response.request)  // original URL request
                print(response.response) // URL response
                print(response.data)     // server data
                print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

                if let JSON = response.result.value {
                    self.mypickerview.delegate = self
                    self.mypickerview.dataSource = self
                    self.pickerData = [JSON["One"] as! String, JSON["Two"] as! String, JSON["Three"] as! String, JSON["Four"] as! String]

                    self.mypickerview.delegate = self;

                }




        }
```

but the problem is that with this code, while it manages to get the data successfully, it isn't showing in the picker view:

```
// Setup the session to make REST GET call.  Notice the URL is https NOT http!!
let postEndpoint: String = "https://example.com/json.json"
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint)!

// Make the POST call and handle it in a completion handler
session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { ( data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    // Make sure we get an OK response
    guard let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where
        realResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("Not a 200 response")
            return
    }

    // Read the JSON
    do {
        if let ipString = NSString(data:data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
            // Print what we got from the call
            print(ipString)

            // Parse the JSON to get the data
            let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            let One = jsonDictionary["One"] as! String
            let Two = jsonDictionary["Two"] as! String
            let Three = jsonDictionary["One"] as! String
            let Four = jsonDictionary["One"] as! String


            self.mypickerview.delegate = self
            self.mypickerview.dataSource = self
            self.pickerData = [One, Two, Three, Four]
            self.mypickerview.delegate = self;



        }
    } catch {
        print("bad things happened")
    }

}).resume()
```

What could the issue be with the second code that's preventing the options in the picker view from showing up?

Comment: Are you sure you are in the main queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after

```
self.pickerData = [One, Two, Three, Four]
```

Call the following to forcibly reload the data in main thread as @SaintThread has mentioned in the comment

```
self.mypickerview.reloadAllComponents()
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to change pickerView - call this method!

```
self.mypickerview.reloadAllComponents()
```